# Word breaking in question titles of question list is too aggressive

Tags: bug, design, title, question-lists

Recently a change was made that resulted in question titles in the question list having word breaks, presumably to resolve issues with question titles with an incredibly long "word" in them. However the implementation of the word breaking is so aggressive that it's splitting closure tags such as:

> ... [duplicate]

splitting into:

> ... [dupli-
>
> cate]

[image: Image showing a question in the question list with the title: "How can I see the all-time reputation graph of another user profile? [dupli-cate]"]

---

It also splits what I would consider to be far too early into a word:

> ... at-
>
> tribute ...

Where a word break happens two letters into a word it would be preferable for the entire word to be moved onto the next line.

[image: Image showing a question in the question list with the title: "On SO: Cookie "_ga" will be soon rejected because it has the "SameSite" at-tribute set to "None""]

---

Lastly, I would consider it preferable not to split on the last word of the title:

> ... import-
>
> tant?

[image: Image showing a question in the question list with the title: "Is having the ability to apply rich text formatting inside code blocks impor-tant"]

---

My preference would be for word breaks to only be added where absolutely necessary in order to prevent titles breaking out of their appropriate bounds.

Comment: N.B. The 2nd/3rd issues mentioned here are potentially more preference. The first however I would consider to be an actual bug. The post's status isn't part of the question title and is a single entity and should be kept as such, it shouldn't be broken in any way.

Comment: I think the primary issue here is `hyphens: auto !important`. It's unclear why we need that style. As long as `word-break: break-word` is set (which it is), extremely long words still get wrapped without the inconvenience of mid-word hyphenation.

Comment: It changed a week or two ago. I have been waiting for this meta post...

Comment: @CodyGray com-e o-n, hyp-hen-at-ion is-n't a-ll th-at b-ad

Comment: @PeterMortensen I first noticed it a couple days ago, had no idea when it actually started

Comment: @Nick stands with Ukraine: It is more pronounced at high zoom levels.